# Batch-Input of .csv Files to SQL-DB via Java

Tags: java, sql, csv

is it possible to batch-input couple of .csv files inside a folder into a MSSQL Database?

Let say i have a folder which contains 10 .csv Files.
Now what i'm looking for is a .jar programm let say csv2db.jar, which i would call like:
csv2db.jar -h HOST -p PORT -d DATABASE -u USER -p PASSWORD
which imports the .csv-Files in to the DATABASE

TABNAME = FILENAME
FIELDTYPES  = (always VARCHAR(MAX)) VARCHAR(255)

If tables already exists = delete and create new tables (maybe a parameter?)

CSV = https://code.google.com/p/opencsv/
MSSQL JDBC = http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Thank you for any Codeexamples, Hints etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but it might be a lot of work for something that's already built into SQL Server.

I'd recommend that you first try to make use of BCP instead of a Java application. BCP is a command-line tool that you can call from Java using Process Builder (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html for help) if you really need to wrap it in a Java program for some reason.

That way, you can use a tool designed to do exactly what you want to do, instead of trying to create your own. Please visit http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx for more information about BCP.  This utility has been part of SQL server for a significant time, so it's stable and well-documented.

BCP allows you to control the import, what happens when data exists, how to format or manipulate the data etc.